# Best practise to query a SQL Server database via Web Service in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I need to create a series of Web Services using Web Developer 2010 Express running on top of IIS.

The Web Service will need to query and manipulate a back-end SQL Server database.

Having searched around the internet, I haven't got enough informative answer about what the best practise for it is (as simple as possible).

Any idea will be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: More info: I am using SQL Server 2008 and programming language is C#. Either SOAP or REST would be OK. Yes, a "tutorial" would be best describing my purpose. A simple working example would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layer on top of your database, `facade`, implemented in WCF that exposes the particular CRUD operations. You'd then be able to allow clients (like your current WCF services) to "talk" to the `facade` that's abstracting/protecting your database.

Comment: Thanks Xander. Could you plz give me a working example for it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out more info than you've provided before you can move forward.  Are your web services going to be SOAP or REST?  Is your code going to be in C# or VB.NET?  What version of SQL server are you using?  Establish these first, then you can move forward.

Visit http://connectionstrings.com/ to find out the appropriate connection string for your SQL Server.

Your question says 'Best Practices', which would mean that we would probably be talking about security and design optimization.  But from the lack of information you provide, I think you're looking more for a tutorial rather than 'Best Practices'.  Investigate the questions above first, then come back if you still have questions.